How to manage resources if you use CorutineScope?
I am using CoroutineScope, should i cancel it or not?
application is written using Spring boot 3, kotlin.
expecting stdout:
start job
finish job
job in the CoroutineScope

I am afraid memory leak.
But singleton bean will be created one time during app creation.
If this memory leak will appears, how i can find it in VisualVM ?
@Component
class AppCoroutineScope(
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO,
) : CoroutineScope



@Service
class MySingletonSpringBean(
    // implemented as singleton
    private val coroutineScope: AppCoroutineScope
) {
    
    fun mySuperFunction(){
        println("start job")
        coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("job in the CoroutineScope")
        }
        println("finish job")
    }
    @PreDestroy
    fun onBeanDestroy(){
        coroutineScope.cancel() // i think this call of cancel() function is useless because coroutineScope won't be launched after application will be stopped. Am i wrong?
    }
}


The cancellation for an application-wide scope is indeed a bit pointless. But the problem is rather about the coroutines launched in that scope. Only launch coroutines that really need to live for the whole application's life, otherwise it's no better than GlobalScope. For other coroutines, try to find a more appropriate scope/lifetime.

What do you mean? 1. It is similar to GlobalScope, but we can’t control GlobalScope.
2. It is singleton bean that works with particular threadpool, and i am using it in the whole application. So if i use it as spring bean this coroutineScope will not be alive after application will be stopped.
3. Using GlobalScope is bad practice.

"Using GlobalScope is bad practice" - yes, but do you know why? The reason is that GlobalScope doesn't provide structured concurrency because its lifespan is that of your application (it doesn't have a job and is never cancelled). So, launching coroutines in such a scope is bad practice if they are not supposed to live for the whole application lifetime. That's the point I was trying to make. In this regard, your application scope is similar to GlobalScope - hence my warning: be careful which coroutines you launch in it.

It's still useful to have an application scope over just using GlobalScope for these few coroutines that do need to live forever, because you can indeed customize the context as you said (thread pool, exception handler, etc.). But it should be considered with the same care. So saying "GlobalScope is bad practice" as a way to justify using an app-wide scope doesn't make sense - that's not the reason why.
